# Issue with POST request to API - Error 500 and Unrecognized Token

Tags: reactjs, server, axios, fetch-api

I'm encountering an issue when sending a POST request to an API in my React application. When attempting to save a checklist, I receive a 500 server error, and in the console, I get the following error message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba9p6.png)

I'm using fetch to make the request, and I've also tried with the axios library, but the problem persists.

Here is the code for my request:

```
const accessToken = '29283b3ef76dcce0b65c77cf41f6cb86400920f2';
const baseURL = 'https://greenvelvet.alwaysdata.net/pfc';

const handleSaveChecklist = async () => {
  // ... (other parts of the code)
  
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/checklist/add`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(checklistData),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('Server response:', data);
    setCreateMessage(`Checklist "${checklistData.title}" created.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error saving the checklist:', error);
    setCreateMessage(`Failed to create checklist. Error: ${error.message || 'Unknown error'}`);
  }
};
```

Additionally, I've verified that my token is correct, but I still receive the following server error in the JSON response: {"error":"Token is not unknown"}

Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT : So to be more precise I am currently working on a project that involves making asynchronous AJAX calls to the following API: https://greenvelvet.alwaysdata.net/pfc/.

I have followed the instructions in the API documentation for authentication using a token. I generated a unique token by visiting https://greenvelvet.alwaysdata.net/pfc/subscribe, and I'm using this token in the Authorization header of my requests.

However, when I try to make a POST request to https://greenvelvet.alwaysdata.net/pfc/checklist/add, I encounter a 500 Internal Server Error and i have verified that the endpoint is correct, and it should be expecting a POST request, the access token used in the Authorization header is valid and has the necessary permissions
Despite these checks, the issue persists. I've included the relevant code snippet below for reference:

```js
const accessToken = '29283b3ef76dcce0b65c77cf41f6cb86400920f2';
const baseURL = 'https://greenvelvet.alwaysdata.net/pfc';

const handleSaveChecklist = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/checklist/add`, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(checklistData),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Error happened");
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log('Server Response:', data);
         setCreateMessage(`Checklist "${checklistData.title}" created.`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during checklist save:', error);
         setCreateMessage(`Failed to create checklist. Error: ${error.message || 'Unknown error'}`);
    }
};
```

Comment: It’s not clear how we can diagnose a server-side issue. That’s an odd error message, though.

Comment: Could you please link to the API documentation?

Answer (score -1):

Hard to say. Currently visiting https://greenvelvet.alwaysdata.net/pfc/checklist/add gives me 404 not found error.

I suggest after fetch add if statement because fetch() will only reject a promise if the user is offline, or some unlikely networking error occurs, such a DNS lookup failure. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful),

```
if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Error happened");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try to put 'Authorization' into the quotes.

Comment: That shouldn’t be necessary; it’s fine as-is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).